# How to run nextCmd asychronously in pySnmp

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

My program below fetches out the leaf nodes OIDs (sub oids) values, but when I check out the network traffic in Wireshark, there is a request & response for each OID. That's okay, but now in my program can you help me to hit 5 or n number of parent OIDs so I can walk through all it's child oids asynchronously? Instead for waiting for first parent oid's sub oids to be covered than going next.

WireShark request/response [capture](https://ibb.co/fb5R2x).

My Program:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
import sys

def walk(host, oid):

    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData('public'),
                              UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                              lookupMib=False,
                              lexicographicMode=True):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
            break

        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'), file=sys.stderr)
            break

        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                 print('%s = %s' % varBind)

 walk('10.78.163.39',
      '.1.3.6.1.4.1.5296.1.9.1.1.2.8.115.101.99.101.109.115.57.57.1.47')
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your goal. Do you know all the parent OIDs already? So you want to run GETNEXT for each of the parent OIDs to fetch all sub-OIDs per each parent OID in parallel?

Comment: Yes you catch it perfectly right & yes i know all oid alrdy, I found the same program here: http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/v3arch/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations.html#fetch-two-subtrees-in-parallel
BUT there is issue in this program, if one OID is finished walking with it's sub-OIDs another OID also stops at the same moment instead it should cover all it's sub-OIDs as well, another thing is I want to run it for n number of OIDs(already know). Can you help out llya

Comment: @Ilya Etingof pls guide.

Comment: Asynchronous operations won't give you significant improvement here, as GET NEXT has to be executed sequentially. You should, however, use GET BULK instead, which processes much more data in one run. Sadly Ilya didn't give you that hint.